# Access controller property from another Class in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

today I discovered the following problem while using AngularJS.

My Code is as follows:

```
app.controller("SomeController", function(){

            this.foo = true

            this.changeFoo = function(bool){

                this.foo = bool
            }

            api.check(function(response){
                this.changeFoo(response.bar)
            })
        })
```

(by the way: *response* & *response.bar* are not undefined)

*api* is an instance of my class *API*, defined outside of my Angular-code.

The problem is, that I can not change *this.foo* inside my callback-function.

What can I do to access *this.foo*?

Edit:

I tried to pass *this* as an argument, the result is the same

```
api.check(this, function(scope, response){

                scope.foo = response.bar
            })
```

*scope* seems to be defined inside this function, but the changes doesn't effect anything

Comment: `api.check.call(this, function() { ..`, or just use the classic `var self = this`

Comment: I dont know why, but this does not work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mu4kfbjt/

Comment: var vm = this; so you are a reference to use in api block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `this` to a different variable in your angular code before your Api call. Then use that variable to access your `this` variable. Like this

```
app.controller("SomeController", ['$scope',function($scope){

        this.foo = true;

        this.changeFoo = function(bool){

            this.foo = bool;
            $scope.$apply();
        };
        Var controller=this;

        api.check(function(response){
            controller.changeFoo(response.bar);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: as you can see there are no errors. can you give me a working example?

Comment: its running you just need to use $scope.apply() to update the document